# Copy files together using the registry and a command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, registry, command-prompt

I'm not quite sure what is correct wildcards/syntax to pass the information correctly to the command prompt.

I would like to implement this solution in the registry via right click in `"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CMDCopyBExt\"`

Say I have a bunch of files in a folder but I only want to `copy /b *.csv ALL.csv`.

How can I pass the extension of a file passed as a wildcard through command prompt?

I suppose it would be something like: `%1" copy /b (*).%%(ext?) ALL.%%(ext?)`

Comment: rather you should add `cmd.exe /c copy...` (eventually even the full path to cmd.exe)

Comment: Thank you for your reply npo. Since I posted this question, I tried adding the full path of cmd.exe and just "cmd.exe". Could you kindly provide what you think would be the correct syntax using the example I provided above? If my question is not explicit enough please let me know. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is what I have thus far "cmd.exe" "copy /b" "(*).%1x1" "ALL.%1x1"

Comment: There's no simple way to achieve what you want. For one thing, the command value syntax doesn't provide a way to extract just the extension, so you'd need to run a script that does all the work for you. Also, if you have selected multiple files, the command will be run separately for each selected file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ansgar. I was about hoping there was a easier solution and I was not trying to reinvent the wheel by creating a simple application that would do the same as a simple command prompt. I suppose this time my perseverance did not serve me well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo copy "%~dp1*%~x1" "d:\somefolder"
```

I put an echo in so you can see the command without actually copying.

To see what is happening type

```
call /?
```